# Chrome is masking console.log object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

[image: previous Chrome behavior which directly shows value of keys]

Before this Chrome used to directly reveal the value of key as image above.
But not sure if i accidentally made any changes, it now kind of masked the value with (...) which requires me to perform an extra action to click on the value to reveal it.
How can I get back to previous behavior

[image]

Comment: Is it really for all objects you log? if I recall correctly `(...)` is displayed if a getter is defined for that property, because requesting the value might result in an action.

Comment: You are definitely right. It was my bad, if you could kindly put this as answer i will accept it :)

Comment: You figured it out at the same time I wrote the comment. So answering the question yourself and accepting that one is perfectly fine. The only thing I would add is that this is done by chrome to avoid side effects on the state you want to debug, because a getter could modify existing objects and properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I have just realized that it has nothing to do with Chrome.
The issue was I am using vue which use property getter, so chrome needs me to manually click on the (...) to invoke the getter function.

Comment: Try Vue DevTools ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Go to DevTools settings (the cog wheel).

Check General > Sources > Display variable values inline while debugging.

Try with that or you can go with JSON.stringify

Comment: I already have it checked but the issue preserved, thanks anyway :)